# Python Selenium Can not solving reCaptcha

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, captcha

2capthca not solved my targeting site.
I try using python with selenium to solve this.
My targeting site is: https://visa.vfsglobal.com/ind/en/ltu/login

I got result from 2captcha api. But when I click button got error.

```
pageurl = 'https://visa.vfsglobal.com/ind/en/ltu/login'

google_site_key = '6LfDUY8bAAAAAPU5MWGT_w0x5M-8RdzC29SClOfI'
service_key = '2CAPTCH KEY'
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(pageurl)

WebDriverWait(driver, 50).until(
                    EC.invisibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[1]')))

# Allow Cookie
try:
    WebDriverWait(driver, 5) \
        .until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,
                                           "div#onetrust-button-group button#onetrust-accept-btn-handler"))) \
        .click()
except:
    pass


email = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="mat-input-0"]')
email.send_keys(str('EMAIL'))

password = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="mat-input-1"]')
password.send_keys(str('PASSWORD'))
time.sleep(5)

url = "http://2captcha.com/in.php?key=" + service_key + "&method=userrecaptcha&googlekey=" + google_site_key + "&pageurl=" + pageurl
resp = requests.get(url)

if resp.text[0:2] != 'OK':
    quit('Service error. Error code:' + resp.text)

captcha_id = resp.text[3:]

fetch_url = "http://2captcha.com/res.php?key="+ service_key + "&action=get&id=" + captcha_id

for i in range(1, 10):
    time.sleep(5) # wait 5 sec.
    resp = requests.get(fetch_url)
    print(resp.text)
    if resp.text[0:2] == 'OK':
        break

driver.execute_script('var element=document.getElementById("g-recaptcha-response"); element.style.display="";')
driver.execute_script("""
  document.getElementById("g-recaptcha-response").innerHTML = arguments[0]
""", resp.text[3:])

driver.execute_script('var element=document.getElementById("g-recaptcha-response"); element.style.display="none";')

login = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//span[contains(text(),'Sign In')]")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", login)
time.sleep(2)
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", login)
```

check my attached file to see error

[image: error]

Comment: Congratulations, the captcha worked.

Comment: How?, Not working in my side.

Comment: Read the captcha [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAPTCHA)

Comment: @MarceloPaco I read this. Working with other site. Only not working with this site.

Comment: So okay, you have reported to us that this doesn't work for you, what do you want to ask us?

Comment: When I click Sign In button Its showing error "Mandatory field cannot be left blank"

Comment: Yes, because you didn't fill in a mandatory field.

Comment: I fill mandatory filed. When I solved manually it's work.

Comment: But your script didn't fill it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252817/discussion-between-a-s-m-saief-and-mkrieger1).

Comment: Can You explain where did I miss?